# How to extend Javascript with new while statment

Tags: javascript, syntax, extending

I am trying to create a new way of implementing loops in Javascript. The user would type

> Loop(n)
>   {
>        // code to repeat
>  
>   }

and the new loop function would repeat the code inside the curly brackets 'n' times. It would simply implement a while loop in the back end with a counter variable.

I know how to create prototype functions, but I need more than passing in parameters to a function. I want the loop(n) statement to repeat a block of code specified by the coder.

I've had a look at Sweet.js, but there doesn't seem to be any references to doing what I am proposing.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is what transpilers do. You can't define language semantics and syntax directly from the language itself. You may implement something like a **callback** and execute it inside a while loop, or accept what sweet.js or similars do, un less you want to write your own transpiler.

Comment: Seems to me [Sweet's documentation](https://www.sweetjs.org/doc/tutorial.html#sweet-cond) does suggest you can do this with Sweet.js, did you read through that section?

Comment: I was looking at that same page....but I missed that section. Thanks for pointing it out to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sweet.js documentation does indeed have [an example](https://www.sweetjs.org/doc/tutorial.html#sweet-cond) you can apply to looping. Here's a simple version:

```
syntax loop = function (ctx) {
    const count = ctx.next().value;
    const code = ctx.next().value;
    return #`for (let __n = 0; __n < ${count}; ++__n) ${code}`;
}
```

...though there's probably a better way to create the loop variable.

You'd use that like this:

```
loop 10 {
    // ...your code here...
}
```

[Try it out here](https://www.sweetjs.org/browser/editor.html#syntax%20loop%20=%20function%20(ctx)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20count%20=%20ctx.next().value;%0A%20%20%20%20const%20code%20=%20ctx.next().value;%0A%20%20%20%20return%20#%60for%20(let%20__n%20=%200;%20__n%20%3C%20$%7Bcount%7D;%20++__n)%20$%7Bcode%7D%60;%0A%7D%0Aloop%2010%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Hello%22);%0A%7D)

I'd probably want to specify the identifier to use for the counter:

```
syntax loop = function (ctx) {
    const count = ctx.next().value;
    const identifier = ctx.next().value;
    const code = ctx.next().value;
    return #`for (let ${identifier} = 0; ${identifier} < ${count}; ++${identifier}) ${code}`;
}
```

Then:

```
loop 10 index {
    console.log(index);
}
```

[Try it out here](https://www.sweetjs.org/browser/editor.html#syntax%20loop%20=%20function%20(ctx)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20count%20=%20ctx.next().value;%0A%20%20%20%20const%20identifier%20=%20ctx.next().value;%0A%20%20%20%20const%20code%20=%20ctx.next().value;%0A%20%20%20%20return%20#%60for%20(let%20$%7Bidentifier%7D%20=%200;%20$%7Bidentifier%7D%20%3C%20$%7Bcount%7D;%20++$%7Bidentifier%7D)%20$%7Bcode%7D%60;%0A%7D%0Aloop%2010%20index%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(index);%0A%7D)

I expect there's a way to make the identifier optional if you like.

---

That said, I'd just use a function you pass a callback to:

```js
function loop(end, callback) {
    for (let n = 0; n < end; ++n) {
        callback(n);
    }
}

loop(10, n => console.log(n));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

You can make that more feature-full quite easily:

```js
function loop(end, start, step, callback) {
    if (typeof end !== "number") {
        throw new Error("'end' should be a number");
    }
    if (typeof start === "function") {
        callback = start;
        start = 0;
        step = 1;
    } else if (typeof step === "function") {
        callback = step;
        step = 1;
    }
    if (typeof start !== "number") {
        throw new Error("'start' should be a number");
    }
    if (typeof step !== "number") {
        throw new Error("'step' should be a number");
    }
    for (let n = start; n < end; n += step) {
        callback(n);
    }
}

console.log("loop(3, n => console.log(n));");
loop(3, n => console.log(n));
console.log("loop(3, 1, n => console.log(n));");
loop(3, 1, n => console.log(n));
console.log("loop(6, 0, 2, n => console.log(n));");
loop(6, 0, 2, n => console.log(n));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Your first solution was exactly what I needed. I wanted to avoid using a function because the I wanted people to actually type this new syntax loop(5){code}. The purpose is to create a simple version of Javascript.